# Error, While Connecting To Mlabs Using Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mlab

I am Getting Error While Connecting My Node.js Application to Mlabs Database. I am Using the Below Code, Please Tell me Where I am Wrong.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const MONGO_URL = 'mongodb://dbUser:dbpassword@ds132251.mlab.com:33623/testing11';


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   MongoClient.connect(MONGO_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err, db) => {  
      if (err) {
        return console.log('Error While Connecting to mongodb');
      }
     db.collection("users").find({_id:"5b50e2d3e712fa3g8a8e9a76"}, function(err,result){
        if(err){
            console.log('Error While Finding data from your table');
        }else{
            console.log(result);
        }
     })
   });
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Hey, what is the error you're seeing and what version of the mongodb driver are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the same connection string in your code, I console.log the error and got "MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server". To fix this, make sure the connection string

```
const MONGO_URL = 'mongodb://dbUser:dbpassword@ds132251.mlab.com:33623/testing11'
```

is correct
and also make sure that your network is fine and can connect to mlab.